# Got a button in Excel that was working as an ActiveX control, had to switch to shape, now it's not working 100%

Tags: vba, excel, activex, shapes

I created an activex button for a tracker I was tasked with building at work, activex button worked great but there were endless compatibility and permission issues when I sent it out. Decided to make it a macro enabled shape instead. It's supposed to be a simple button that when you click it, it enters the current time and date into the active cell. That works, the problem is is that it's no longer floating like I had it when it was an activex button, it doesn't follow the active cell down the page. Also -- since it's not activex it doesn't simulate a button click, which I tried to code in, and everything *looks* right, but there is no depression when I click on it. Here's what I have so far.

```
Sub RectangleRoundedCorners1()
Dim vTopType As Variant
Dim iTopInset As Integer
Dim iTopDepth As Integer

    With ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).ThreeD
        vTopType = .BevelTopType
        iTopInset = .BevelTopInset
        iTopDepth = .BevelTopDepth
    End With

    With ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).ThreeD
        .BevelTopType = msoBevelSoftRound
        .BevelTopInset = 12
        .BevelTopDepth = 4
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    With ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).ThreeD
        .BevelTopType = vTopType
        .BevelTopInset = iTopInset
        .BevelTopDepth = iTopDepth
    End With
End Sub

Sub RectangleRoundedCorners1_Click()
    ActiveCell.Value = Now()
    ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "MM/DD/YY hh:mm:ss"
End Sub

Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    With Cells(Windows(1).ScrollRow, Windows(1).ScrollColumn)
        RectangleRoundedCorners1.Top = .Top + 10
        RectangleRoundedCorners1.Left = .Left + 825

    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have the option of putting a form button on the page?  Go to insert on developer tab and choose form button instead of activex button.  Right click the button to set properties and you can choose to let it move with cells or not.  And you can right click to choose a sub when it is clicked.

Comment: I tried that but it wasn't working, The team I hit up to get the recommendation for a macro enabled shape said that can cause a lot of the same issues I was running into with the activex button. Regardless, I'd like to know how to get this working for the macro enabled shapes, including the top portion of the code which should allow the button to show a depressed button when clicked

Comment: I like to use a right-click pop-up menu to initiate special functions.  Ron DeBruin has an excellent code source for that. http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s6/win002.htm   You add your function to the regular right-click pop-up menu, label it something like "Insert Date" - then right-click on any cell and your label will be on the pop-up.  The only drawback is that you must make certain the workbook removes it when closing.  A simple onClose code will do that.

Comment: That's pretty cool, but I don't understand how that helps with my scripting errors that are popping up.

Comment: just meant as an alternative route to inserting a date into a cell.

Comment: Thank you all for the workaround solutions and your creative thinking, however I am currently more concerned with learning what the issue is, rather than working around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shape objects don't have the same methods as an ActiveX object. They also only exist in the Excel workbook, not inside of VB, so you can't just reference them by creating a method with the same name as the object. You could merge those two subs into one, then have assign that sub to the button by right clicking on it and using the "Assign Macro..." option to set that sub to it.

```
Sub ButtonClick()
Dim vTopType As Variant
Dim iTopInset As Integer
Dim iTopDepth As Integer

    With ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).ThreeD
        vTopType = .BevelTopType
        iTopInset = .BevelTopInset
        iTopDepth = .BevelTopDepth
    End With

    With ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).ThreeD
        .BevelTopType = msoBevelSoftRound
        .BevelTopInset = 12
        .BevelTopDepth = 4
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    With ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).ThreeD
        .BevelTopType = vTopType
        .BevelTopInset = iTopInset
        .BevelTopDepth = iTopDepth
    End With

    ActiveCell.Value = Now()
    ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "MM/DD/YY hh:mm:ss"
End Sub
```

As for the getting it to follow the sheet, you need to get a valid reference to the shape object first (this code needs to be inside the module for the worksheet your button is in).
[image]

```
Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)

Dim shButton As Shape

Set shButton = Shapes("RectangleRoundedCorners1")

With Cells(Windows(1).ScrollRow, Windows(1).ScrollColumn)
    shButton.Top = .Top + 10
    shButton.Left = .Left + 825
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try this when I get in tomorrow

Comment: When I try this method, everything looks fine to me, except the following the sheet part, I've now got the macro assigned to "ButtonClick" Instead of "RectangleRoundedCorners1" and when I compile it, I get an error: "Sub or Function not Defined" at:

    Set shbutton = Shapes("RectangleRoundedCorners1")

referencing the word "Shapes"

Comment: I also tried adding a second macro called rectangleroundedcorners1 manually but that just creates a sub with that name and doesn't link it to the object. I think the issue is that I'm unsure how to link that second bit of code to the object

Comment: Is the second piece of code inside the module for the worksheet you need the button to move around in? SelectionChange is a worksheet method in Excel, so it needs to be inside a worksheet module.

Comment: Did that, get the error  - 
"Run time error '-2147024809 (80070057)':
The item with the specified name wasn't found." . I don't know how to make sure the rectangle is *named* anything, so when the code references "RectangleRoundedCorners1" it doesn't find anything. How do I "Name" That object

Comment: Nevermind! I JUST figured it out! Thank you so much for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

The change to the shape happens so fast that the human eye can hardly see it.  I put a for loop to keep the change visible long enough for the user to appreciate the key click.

Put the following code into a regular module, not your worksheet module.  Delete all your worksheet module code related to this shape.

Then right click your shape and "Assign Macro" - to this one in the regular module.  I don't know how to make it stay in place when the user scrolls, but at least this will fix your visual problem.

I also added the date change to cell A1.

```
Sub RectangleRoundedCorners1()
Dim vTopType As Variant
Dim iTopInset As Integer
Dim iTopDepth As Integer

    With ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).ThreeD
        vTopType = .BevelTopType
        iTopInset = .BevelTopInset
        iTopDepth = .BevelTopDepth
    End With

For i = 1 To 70
'   This change happens too quickly for the eye to see
'   Put a small for loop so the visual change can be seen
    With ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).ThreeD
        .BevelTopType = msoBevelSoftRound
        .BevelTopInset = 12
        .BevelTopDepth = 4
        .Visible = True
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).ThreeD.Visible = True
Next i

    With ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).ThreeD
        .BevelTopType = vTopType
        .BevelTopInset = iTopInset
        .BevelTopDepth = iTopDepth
    End With


   ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value = Format(Now(), "mmm dd, yyyy")

End Sub
```